# Office 365 API, error: The token has invalid value 'roles' for the claim type ''

Tags: azure, oauth, ms-office, exchangewebservices, office365

I'm trying to access the office 365 API's, in particular the Exchange APIs.

I am attempting to develop a server / daemon application to poll a shared inbox therefor I am using the 'client_credentials' grant type with OAuth 2.0. I have followed steps to produce an application in Azure Active Directory, you can see from the screen grab the permissions the app has: http://gyazo.com/a2d614a690115f8a6b65de00f46b1599

Eventually I want to develop a Ruby application to pull the data but to begin with I am testing responses with cURL, here is the OAuth Token requrest:

```
curl -X POST https://login.windows.net/TENANT_KEY/oauth2/token \
  -F redirect_uri=http://spreadyDaemon \
  -F grant_type=client_credentials \
  -F resource=https://outlook.office365.com/ \
  -F client_id=XXXX \
  -F client_secret=XXXX=
```

Which returns me a JWT key that looks like this when decoded:

**Header**

```
{
  "x5t": "kriMPdmBvx68skT8-mPAB3BseeA", 
  "alg": "RS256", 
  "typ": "JWT"
}
```

**Claims**

```
{
  "ver": "1.0", 
  "aud": "https://outlook.office365.com/", 
  "iss": "https://sts.windows.net/TENANT_KEY/", 
  "oid": "17fa33ae-a0e9-4292-96ea-24ce8f11df21", 
  "idp": "https://sts.windows.net/TENANT_KEY/", 
  "appidacr": "1", 
  "exp": 1415986833, 
  "appid": "XXXX", 
  "tid": "e625eb3f-ef77-4c02-8010-c591d78b6c5f", 
  "iat": 1415982933, 
  "nbf": 1415982933, 
  "sub": "17fa33ae-a0e9-4292-96ea-24ce8f11df21"
}
```

However when I then use that token to request anything from the Exchange API I get a 401 Unauthorized with the x-ms-diagnostics header set to:

```
x-ms-diagnostics: 2000001;reason="The token has invalid value 'roles' for the claim type ''.";error_category="invalid_token"
```

Here is the full header:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Cache-Control: private
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
request-id: d08d01a8-7213-4a13-a598-08362b4dfa70
Set-Cookie: ClientId=WDALDNO0CAIOOZDZWTA; expires=Sat, 14-Nov-2015 16:40:59 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
X-CalculatedBETarget: am3pr01mb0662.eurprd01.prod.exchangelabs.com
x-ms-diagnostics: 2000001;reason="The token has invalid value 'roles' for the claim type ''.";error_category="invalid_token"
X-DiagInfo: AM3PR01MB0662
X-BEServer: AM3PR01MB0662
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
Set-Cookie: exchangecookie=6bf68da033684824af21af3b0cdea6e3; expires=Sat, 14-Nov-2015 16:40:59 GMT; path=/; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie2=OrganizationAnchor@Fitzdares.onmicrosoft.com=u56Lnp2ejJqBz82am8zJx8zSzcmey9LLyZrI0p6cmp3SycjLm8eazcjIy83IgbmWi4Wbno2ajNGQkZKWnI2QjJCZi9GckJKBzc/Oy9LOzdLOy6vOycXLz8XKxoGaio2PjZvPztGPjZCb0ZqHnJeekZiak56djNGckJI=; expires=Sun, 14-Dec-2014 16:40:59 GMT; path=/EWS; secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie: X-BackEndCookie=OrganizationAnchor@Fitzdares.onmicrosoft.com=u56Lnp2ejJqBz82am8zJx8zSzcmey9LLyZrI0p6cmp3SycjLm8eazcjIy83IgbmWi4Wbno2ajNGQkZKWnI2QjJCZi9GckJKBzc/Oy9LOzdLOy6vOycXLz8XKxg==; expires=Sun, 14-Dec-2014 16:40:59 GMT; path=/EWS; secure; HttpOnly
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
X-FEServer: DB4PR02CA0026
WWW-Authenticate: Bearer client_id="00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000", trusted_issuers="00000001-0000-0000-c000-000000000000@*", authorization_uri="https://login.windows.net/common/oauth2/authorize", error="invalid_token",Basic Realm="",Basic Realm=""
Date: Fri, 14 Nov 2014 16:40:59 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

I'm not sure whether I've misunderstood some documentation or missed a step somewhere. The JWT however is missing any scopes for access. I'm not sure of how to add specific permissions to the application manifest as described here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/application-manifest#AppManifest_ExchangeScopes

This is how my **manifest** appears:

```
{
  "allowActAsForAllClients": null,
  "appId": "XXXX",
  "appMetadata": {
    "version": 0,
    "data": []
  },
  "appRoles": [],
  "availableToOtherTenants": false,
  "displayName": "Fitzdares",
  "errorUrl": null,
  "groupMembershipClaims": null,
  "homepage": "http://spreadyDaemon",
  "identifierUris": [
    "http://spreadyDaemon"
  ],
  "keyCredentials": [],
  "knownClientApplications": [],
  "logoutUrl": null,
  "oauth2AllowImplicitFlow": false,
  "oauth2AllowUrlPathMatching": false,
  "oauth2Permissions": [],
  "oauth2RequirePostResponse": false,
  "passwordCredentials": [
    {
      "customKeyIdentifier": null,
      "endDate": "2016-11-14T16:30:45.0745603Z",
      "keyId": "46cce171-ed65-4828-8af7-d02af950e44a",
      "startDate": "2014-11-14T16:30:45.0745603Z",
      "value": null
    }
  ],
  "publicClient": null,
  "replyUrls": [
    "http://spreadyDaemon"
  ],
  "requiredResourceAccess": [
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0ff1-ce00-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "3b5f3d61-589b-4a3c-a359-5dd4b5ee5bd5",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "185758ba-798d-4b72-9e54-429a413a2510",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "75767999-c7a8-481e-a6b4-19458e0b30a5",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "5eb43c10-865a-4259-960a-83946678f8dd",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "resourceAppId": "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000",
      "resourceAccess": [
        {
          "id": "5778995a-e1bf-45b8-affa-663a9f3f4d04",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "78c8a3c8-a07e-4b9e-af1b-b5ccab50a175",
          "type": "Scope"
        },
        {
          "id": "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6",
          "type": "Scope"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "samlMetadataUrl": null,
  "defaultPolicy": [],
  "extensionProperties": [],
  "objectType": "Application",
  "objectId": "8af97a9f-74c7-499d-b29a-7fca6926d84e",
  "deletionTimestamp": null,
  "createdOnBehalfOf": null,
  "createdObjects": [],
  "manager": null,
  "directReports": [],
  "members": [],
  "memberOf": [],
  "owners": [],
  "ownedObjects": []
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Venkat,

I suspect the problem is in how you're requesting the token. You're using `grant_type=client_credentials`, which isn't supported by Exchange Online (at least not for now). The only grant type supported by Exchange is `authorization_code`. See Matthias' comment on 11/4 on this post:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/03/25/using-oauth2-to-access-calendar-contact-and-mail-api-in-exchange-online-in-office-365.aspx

This may also be helpful:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2014/10/28/oauth2-in-action-with-the-release-of-office-365-calendar-contacts-and-mail.aspx

UPDATE: Client credential flow is now supported! http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx

Jason

Comment: Thanks for the answer Jason. Just to quote Mathhias response on the client_credential issues (for anyone else with a similar problem to me) _"There is no way in the code flow to avoid username/password. We're working on a client credential flow for later this fall that will give you the functionality required to run background services. For this you will not need a username/password, but the application will directly assert its identity and authenticate as itself."_.  
Unforuniately as I am trying to write a headless daemon I will need to wait for this feature.

Comment: Hi Nick, I just updated my answer.  We are very close to support client credential flow, so please stay tuned for an announcement in a few weeks.  Thanks for using Office 365 REST APIs.

Comment: Venkat, any update on client credentials flow. If not where should I be looking for announcements?

Comment: Nick, you can follow me on Twitter (@JasonJohMSFT) or watch the Exchange Dev blog at http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/. I'll definitely be posting when we go live with it.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the detailed info!  Your issue may be the same as the one discussed in [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904789/office-365-api-erroraccessdenied-access-is-denied-check-credentials-and-try-ag) and unchecking "Have full access to a user's mailbox" may fix the issue you are seeing.

Please let me know if you have any questions or if you are getting access denied even after unchecking this permission.

**[UPDATE]:** Jason is right - we don't yet support client-credential flow.  However, we are very close to making this available.  So, please stay tuned for a blog in a few weeks with an announcement that it is available and instructions to use it.

**[UPDATE]:** Support for service accounts is now available. Please see our [blog announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx) for more details.

Comment: Hi Venkat,

Thanks for the quick response, unfortunately this didn't fix the issue. It seems my problem is the lack of roles in the JWT claim response.

Comment: Hi Nick, Thanks for the update.  Let me check with my team on why your request is failing.  Thanks.

Comment: Hi Nick, Service account support is now available. Please take a look at my updated answer for more info. Thanks.