# office 365 integration with my web app

Tags: office365

hi friends,
             iam trying to integrate office 365 with my application.just few days back when i made a get request to https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Events with header part as followed:
Authorization:Bearer access token
 it showed all events of office 365 account.but when i try doing the same thing it is showing an error saying that
x-ms-diagnostics: 2000001;reason="Unable to read or process token, additional details: 'Jwt10204: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.JwtSecurityTokenHandler' cannot read this string: 'eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsIng1dCI6ImtyaU1QZG1Cdng2OHNrVDgtbVBBQjNCc2VlQSJ9.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.f_-kJQiSk0q-CAFK7JnirIT2-Tf2aSl6vgk-gTdmufm-e6siffqSRcyr3vIEfb62NN-Mfwv8coccaE7WlbxV7EWC9GGgoEKin-CkWPZFZZiCeKo_3nl8GYZWAfVf_u7eh9I3pfH9Trd5S7Se6lP1osUXajP2VLUYtmQ0nXWaJVKx9MvdhMiHjYdHRyA8oTyjWF0vII2UBkn8U8uN9oH9GSD3XKumsy52wbC87M3IO-A0pb-qlBDDM3OW2w3Uaw870hj-j01l9rDX_z5PnshZqYMqXwR7RHOe3vcHycykcElb_Rl0yVzS207uRfP30_HCyBLt7Vlho9AOLTJQVE07Aw:'.%0aThe string needs to be in compact JSON format, which is of the form: '..'.'.";error_category="invalid_token"

Comment: Hi Ankita,  Thanks for reporting the issue!  Can you please provide the list of permissions that your app requests a user and all response headers for a failed request?  We will look into the reason why this is failing. Thanks.

Comment: i have given all permissions for my app.i mean all exchange and sharepoint permissions.and tried making request to api in fiddler.. and made a get request to https://outlook.office365.com/ews/odata/Me/Events

Comment: Authorization: Bearer accesstoken

Comment: if any more details required please let me know.i have almost spent 3 to 4 days on it.2 days back office 365 was down.but now when it is up still iam facing same issue

Answer (score 1):

Try copying the access token and pasting into a JWT parser like http://jwt.calebb.net/. The string you included in your original post doesn't look like valid base 64. There seems to be a trailing ':' that is causing it not to parse.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at a related [Stack Overflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904789/office-365-api-erroraccessdenied-access-is-denied-check-credentials-and-try-ag/26910344#26910344) that should help solve your problem.  The issue is that you have selected all permissions and this includes the permission "Have full access to a user's mailbox".  That permission is intended for Exchange Web Services SOAP API and not the Office 365 REST API you are using.  Unchecking that permission for your app should make the requests succeed.

Selecting all permissions when trying out an API is natural but we have a bug on our side that is most likely causing your requests to fail.  We are in the process of deploying a fix that addresses this issue by ignoring the "Have full access to a user's mailbox" for REST API requests and the fix should be deployed by end of January.  Sorry for the inconvenience.

Please let me know if you try that and your request is still failing.

Thanks,

Venkat

Comment: hey venkat ,the get request to mail api https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages is working perfect.but when i make post request to mail https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/sendmail it is throwing an error saying that forbidden request.which permission should i give to send a mail request

Comment: Hi Ankita, You need "Send mail as a user" permission for sendmail.

Comment: i tried with send mail as user.it is not working.but when i make get request it works.