# Access denied for Room Calendar in Office 365 API

Tags: php, rest, curl, office365

I am writing an application in PHP using the Office 365 REST API that pulls down a list of all events for a meeting room. I have authorised the application and can pull back a list of the room events by navigating to the URL through my browser, however, as soon as I try to make the request through CURL I get the following response.

```
{"error":{"code":"ErrorAccessDenied","message":"Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."}}
```

My PHP is as follows

```
public function getCalendarEvents($token, $calendar) {

    $url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/$calendar/events";
    //$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events";

    $headers = array('Authorization: Bearer ' . $token, 'Content-Type: application/json', 'Accept:application/json');

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
    //print_r($info['request_header']);

    curl_close($ch);
    print_r($output);
}
```

I have tried passing in the email address of the room as both

```
$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/email@example.com/events";
```

and

```
$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/Users('email@example.com')/Events";
```

Neither of which work. I am able to pull back all calendar events for myself using

```
$url = "https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/events";
```

I am an admin on the Office 365 portal, as well as being set to have full permissions on the room. In my research I came across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904789/office-365-api-erroraccessdenied-access-is-denied-check-credentials-and-try-ag) SO answer, but unchecking this option in Azure makes no difference.

Very similar issue seems to be reported [here](https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/suggestions/6762997-with-o365-rest-api-i-m-trying-to-access-a-mailbox)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Today, we don't support an authenticated user accessing another user's mail, calendar or contacts using OAuth.  That is why your request is failing when you retrieve the conference room's calendar but working for your own calendar.  This request works using the browser, because you are using Basic authentication, and we don't recommend this for your app.  If you do want to try out requests using OAuth, you can do so using our [OAuth sandbox](https://oauthplay.azurewebsites.net/).

The good news is that we are very close to releasing support for OAuth client credential flow that will enable an app, with consent from the tenant admin, to access any mailbox in the tenant.  Since you are a tenant admin, as soon as we release this feature, you will be able to authorize the app to access the calendars of your tenant's conference rooms.  So, please stay tuned for an announcement in the coming weeks.

**[UPDATE]:** Support for service accounts is now available. Please see our [blog announcement](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/exchangedev/archive/2015/01/22/building-demon-or-service-apps-with-office-365-mail-calendar-and-contacts-apis-oauth2-client-credential-flow.aspx) for more details and let us know if you have any questions.

Comment: Thanks @Venkat. That's good to know, thought I was going crazy. As the application I am building will not be released to the public, I am comfortable with authentication being done via basic rather than OAuth. Is the basic authentication done against my email address and password? And does it need any of the credentials that have been set up through Azure. Can't seem to find any documentation on basic auth.

Comment: Hi Pete, Basic auth just requires your email address and password.  However, we are on a path to disable Basic auth as supporting it was a temporary measure while we built the OAuth playground I mentioned in my answer.  So, if you use Basic auth, you will need to update your code when we drop support for Basic auth.  You may want to wait for the service account support as we are really close to getting it out there :)  Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Presenting the app to the bosses tomorrow morning! So will code it alongside and switch when released. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Pete - Thanks for the update.  Hope your presentation goes well!

Comment: Hi Pete, Service account support is now available.  Please take a look at my updated answer for more info.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to sent your secret code.
And if your program attempt many times may blocked as spammer.

Check it out:
http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/2630976

To fix this problem, reset the user's password. To do this, follow these steps:
Open a web browser, browse to the Office 365 portal (https://portal.office.com), and then sign in by using the user's expired credentials.
When you're prompted, enter a new Office 365 password for the user. Make sure that the password meets the criteria for Office 365.

Comment: That's not the case, as I am able to get my own mailbox as well as the data through a browser. Also, rooms do not have passwords as far as I am aware

Comment: @PeteSimmons simply open https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/users/$calendar/events in browser, login screen shows up and it request username and password.

Comment: yes it does and I get the data back via browser, as per my question. The problem is in getting the data via PHP