# microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again

Tags: outlook, office365, exchange-server, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

We have added a user to our enterprise office365 account , We were able to send a few emails but when we are trying to send more emails using ews api 
we are getting the below exception

```
microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.exception.service.remote.ServiceResponseException: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again., Cannot save changes made to an item to store.
```

Could someone please point if we need to provide additional permission to this user to send emails , if so could you please let us know which permissions to provide

Updated this user with admin role but still no luck getting the same exception

Comment: You need to check your SMTP Server credentials...and probably SSH.

Comment: Thanks for your response Allan ! But we have an admin user on this account from which we are able to send emails without this exception, only problem is with this account

Comment: This is stating that you "Cannot save changes made to an item to store" I think you may have permissions to send I think you have a quota on your store to save to it.

Comment: We are adding an extended property to the email and saving it  using the email.setExtendedProperty(emailIdPropDef, propSetId.toString)
      email.sendAndSaveCopy()

Answer (score 1):

**Symptoms
POA background task Update settings for mailbox fails with the following error:**

*Task ID    5483156
Queue name     DomainService00022874
Task name   Update settings for resource mailbox 'testbox' (id=576829) Task description   Update settings for resource mailbox 'testbox' (id=576829)
Queue status    Failed
Start not earlier than    Dec-19-2011 22:32
Method name    setResourceMailBoxInfoHandler on OBJREF:Exchange:0:getMailBox:576829 Last execution output    Provisioning request failed. Cannot save changes made to an item to store.
Error position:
At C:\Program Files\Parallels\Windows Provisioning Engine\Providers\SW Managed Exchange\ModifyResourceMailbox.ps1:172 char:25 + Set-CalendarProcessing @calendarProcessingProps
 Type: Parallels.Wpe.PowerShell.PowerShellException.`*
**Cause
The target mailbox has been created with a disk space quota of zero. It is impossible to save its properties due to the lack of assigned disk space.**

**Resolution
Increase the disk space quota for the mailbox and resubmit the task.**

[PS] C:>\ Set-Mailbox "user mail id" -ProhibitSendQuota  -ProhibitSendReceiveQuota  -IssueWarningQuota

Comment: Thanks for your answer Allan ! this a E3 license user we are using office365 could you please suggest if we could increase the disk space  via the office admin center ? As currently we haven't configured the mail box on a particular machine

Comment: 1 Each user initially receives 100 GB of storage in the archive mailbox. When auto-expanding archiving is turned on, additional storage is automatically added when the 100 GB storage capacity is reached. For more information, see Overview of unlimited archiving in Office 365. See the Office 365 Roadmap for details about availability.

Comment: We created this user only yesterday if that is the case i don't think we even used 20MB of the allocated 100GB space.....

Comment: Check out this web site: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/blog/2015/04/15/office-365-now-supports-larger-email-messages-up-to-150-mb/

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link ! but the email message we are trying to send is very small i believe it's less than 1MB

Comment: maybe this can help:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26904789/office-365-api-erroraccessdenied-access-is-denied-check-credentials-and-try-ag

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173284/discussion-between-user2359997-and-allan-f-gagnon).